# How to put text on right centre of image view on constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Following is a part of my whole xml of constraint Layout.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
            style="@style/DeviceManagementImageView"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sos"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_apn_not_set"
            style="@style/DeviceManagementHeaderText"
            android:text="Apn not set"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set" />
```

What I am trying to do is get the text view on exact centre on the right side of image view. In linear layout we achieve it mostly by gravity. Here I am using `marginTop` to achieve the same . So can I do the same by using any property . Is there a property something like `rightOfCentreOf` ?
Thanks

Comment: Please add this app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set"

Comment: Do you want to set the text between the center of the image and end of the image ?

Comment: @MathaN No  just at the centre , on the right with little space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pls add one line in your textview

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
```

also remove **android:layout_marginTop="5dp"**

hope it help you

Answer (score 4):

Try this, If you want to move the text to the right or left use Horizontal bias, If you want to move your text to the top or bottom use vertical bias.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_apn_not_set"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.63"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/AmountLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/Amount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Amount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="NILESH"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/AmountLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_apn_not_set"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Apn not set"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img_apn_not_set"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"** and give all 4 side constraint it will be at center

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_apn_not_set"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Apn not set"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/img_apn_not_set"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It will look like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks , did not understand this "give all 4 side containter " you mean all four side the image view. ?

Comment: Sorry that is **constraint** like **Top_toTopOf**, **Bottom_toBottomOf** , right and left too